# Storing MongoDB field value in python variable

Tags: python, mongodb

Storing MongoDB field value in python variable

I am very new to MongoDB so please bear with me as this might be a very remedial question.

I have created and populated a MongoDB database with “tenant information”

```
    def insert(Object, Index):  
       db.Tenant.insert(
        {
       "index":Index,
       "object":Object 
        })
```

Object is a dictionary of tenant specific data (name, lease term etc…)

I am able to print all of my tenant information to command prompt with:

```
   tenantDB = db.Tenant.find()

   print '\n All data from EmployeeData Database \n'
   for tenant in tenantDB:
        print 'new tenant'
        print '\n'
        print tenant
```

however I need to store the values of my tenant dictionary into python variables to perform statistical operations.

I would like to do something like

```
  ***(PSUEDO CODE)***
  tenantDB = db.Tenant.find()
  tenantOne = tenantDB.tenant[1].object[‘price’]
```

^this would ideally return the name of tenant 1 in my database.

***Generally I just need to understand how ‘get out’ values from my database.

Answer (score 0):

What driver / library do you use? With pymongo (https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/#overview) you simply get a list of dictionaries.

```
for d in db.tenant.find():
  sum += d["price"] # or whatever
```

Comment: Thank you! While I was not able to reach directly into my dictionary with the price key. I was able to go d['object']['price'] -- where 'object' is the dictionary of tenant parameters which I read to the database. I am using pymongo's "MongoClient". Best, G.